# Display Richtext in WP7 app

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-toolkit

I want to display an about text in my WP7 app. But it contains links, bold text and an bullet point list. Is there an **easy way to display this as some kind of richtext or html?** I don't want to build this using a stackpanel with textblocks and hyperlinks ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Mango release of Windows Phone bumped the Silverlight version from 3 to 4. As part of this they brought in the RichTextBox control that may do what you need. '

One article (admittedly old) about is [First Look at RichTextBox Control](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Windows-Phone-7-Mango-First-look-at-RichTextBox-control).

Comment: Yeap, you need to download the latest SDK from http://create.msdn.com, once installed your project will have an "Upgrade" option when you right click on it in the Solution Explorer.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an HTML page or file to display, you should use the [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431797%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) control. It supports all the basic functionality you'd expect from a web browser; html markup, styling, anchor tags jumps to other resources or locations with in you page.

To display a file located inside a Visual Studio project, you'll need to do something like [this](http://programming4.us/mobile/2466.aspx). Let me know if you need additional information. Hope this helps.

Al.

=== updated ===

```
/// <summary>
/// Contains extension methods for the WebBrowser control.
/// </summary>
public static class WebBrowserExtensions {

    private static void SaveFileToIsoStore(String fileName) {
        //These files must match what is included in the application package,
        //or BinaryStream.Dispose below will throw an exception.
        using(IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()) {
            if (false == isoStore.FileExists(fileName)) {
                StreamResourceInfo sr = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(fileName, UriKind.Relative));
                using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(sr.Stream)) {
                    byte[] data = br.ReadBytes((int)sr.Stream.Length);
                    SaveToIsoStore(fileName, data);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void SaveToIsoStore(string fileName, byte[] data) {
        string strBaseDir = string.Empty;
        string delimStr = "/\\";
        char[] delimiter = delimStr.ToCharArray();
        string[] dirsPath = fileName.Split(delimiter);

        using (IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()) {
            //Recreate the directory structure
            for (int i = 0; i < dirsPath.Length - 1; i++) {
                strBaseDir = System.IO.Path.Combine(strBaseDir, dirsPath[i]);
                isoStore.CreateDirectory(strBaseDir);
            }

            //Remove existing file
            if (isoStore.FileExists(fileName)) {
                isoStore.DeleteFile(fileName);
            }

            //Write the file
            using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(isoStore.CreateFile(fileName))) {
                bw.Write(data);
                bw.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void NavigateToHtmlFile(this WebBrowser webBrowser, String fileName) {
        SaveFileToIsoStore(fileName);
        using (IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()) {

            if (isoStore.FileExists(fileName)) {
                webBrowser.Navigate(new Uri(fileName, UriKind.Relative));
            } else {
                //something bad has happened here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then in your xaml

```
MyWebControl.NavigateToHtmlFile(pathToHtmlFile);
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid using the WebBrowser control, because it feels a bit over the top to me ...

Comment: hmmmmmm... explain a bit over the top? Code wise it's very clean, are you concerned about the memory/CPU overhead of creating this control?

Comment: As I said, just a feeling. I tried the WebBrowser now, but don't get the page to be displayed. I added the html file to the project and marked it as Embedded Ressource. Then I set Source to "/MyApp;component/About.html" ... I also tried to use the Navigate method and an RelativeUri ... to no avail. Where is my mistake?

Comment: The WebControl can't display files bundled in the XAP, only files on IsolateFileStorage. The first time you want to display a local html file you are required to 'copy' the file from the bundled resource and 'save' it the phone's local file system (IsolatedFileStorage). From there on the Navigate method will work as expected. I've included my code, which is an extension method, to do this. Otherwise feel free to try the answer proposed by @Nigel

Comment: +1 Using HTML and CSS in the Web Browser Control is extremely flexible and easy to use even for a beginner.

Comment: the big problem with webcontrol is the background alway in white. and you can't modify the background color